# Laravel drop down filter without search button

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a page with doctors listing. All the doctors belongs to specific category: gynecology, surgery, urology etc.

How can I filter them with a select drop down without using submit button? I know this is possible to achieve with Ajax, but I need help.

Here's my code:

DoctorsController

```
public function doctorsList() {
    $doctors = Doctor::orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(20);
    $categories = Category::all();
    return view('doctors-list', compact('doctors', 'categories'));
}
```

doctors-list.blade.php

```
  <div class="filter text-center">
    <select name="category_id">
      <option value="all">All</option>
      @foreach($categories as $category)
        <option value="{{ $category->id }}">{{ $category->title }}</option>
      @endforeach
    </select>
  </div>
  @foreach($doctors as $doctor)
    <div class="article">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <div class="image"><a href="{{ route('doctor', $doctor->slug) }}"><img width="260" src="{{ Storage::url($doctor->image) }}" /></a></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-9 right">
          <div class="title"><h3>{{ $doctor->title }}</h3></div>
          <div class="body">{!! strip_tags(str_limit($doctor->body, 300)) !!}</div>
          <div class="more"><a href="{{ route('doctor', $doctor->slug) }}">More></a></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  @endforeach
```

Route:

```
Route::get('/doctors', 'DoctorsController@doctorsList')->name('doctorsList');
```

Migrations (two separate files):

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateDoctorsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('doctors', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('doctors');
    }
}


<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateDoctorTranslationsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('doctor_translations', function (Blueprint $table) {
          $table->increments('id');
          $table->integer('doctor_id')->unsigned();
          $table->string('locale')->index();

          // The actual fields to store the content of your entity. You can add whatever you need.
          $table->string('title');
          $table->string('slug')->unique();
          $table->string('image');
          $table->text('body');
          $table->integer('category_id');
          $table->string('status');
          $table->integer('user_id');

          $table->unique(['doctor_id', 'locale']);
          $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('doctor_translations');
    }
}
```

Models:
Doctor.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Dimsav\Translatable\Translatable;

class Doctor extends Model
{
  use Translatable;

  public $translatedAttributes = ['title', 'slug', 'image', 'body', 'category_id','status', 'user_id'];

  public function category() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
  }
}
```

DoctorTranslation.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Cviebrock\EloquentSluggable\Sluggable;

class DoctorTranslation extends Model
{
  use Sluggable;

  public $timestamps = false;

  /**
   * Return the sluggable configuration array for this model.
   *
   * @return array
   */
  public function sluggable()
  {
      return [
          'slug' => [
              'source' => 'title',
              'onUpdate' => true
          ]
      ];
  }
}
```

Right now with this code I'm displaying all the doctors and I have created the Select box that gets the categories from the database.

How can I filter them when I choose a different category from the drop down?

I'm using Laravel 5.5

Comment: try whit datatable https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter.html

Comment: OR if you want to keep the Select feature https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html will be better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a query parameter to filter the doctors by category. This would be the updated controller method:

```
public function doctorsList(Request $request)
{
    $query = (new Doctor)->newQuery();
    $selectedCategory = $request->get('category_id', 'all');

    if (is_numeric($selectedCategory )) {
        $query->whereTranslation('category_id', $selectedCategory);
    }

    $doctors = $query->orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(20);
    $categories = Category::all();

    return view('doctors-list', compact('doctors', 'categories', 'selectedCategory'));
}
```

And the blade template would be something like:

```
<form action="{{route('doctorsList')}}" method="get">
  <div class="filter text-center">
    <select name="category_id" onchange="this.form.submit()">
      <option value="all">All</option>
      @foreach($categories as $category)
        <option value="{{ $category->id }}" {{$category->id == $selectedCategory ? 'selected' : ''}}>{{ $category->title }}</option>
      @endforeach
    </select>
  </div>
</form>
  @foreach($doctors as $doctor)
    <div class="article">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <div class="image"><a href="{{ route('doctor', $doctor->slug) }}"><img width="260" src="{{ Storage::url($doctor->image) }}" /></a></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-9 right">
          <div class="title"><h3>{{ $doctor->title }}</h3></div>
          <div class="body">{!! strip_tags(str_limit($doctor->body, 300)) !!}</div>
          <div class="more"><a href="{{ route('doctor', $doctor->slug) }}">More></a></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  @endforeach
```

Of course, you can put the onchange handler somewhere in your js files instead of doing it inline.

I considered you named the doctors listing route as `doctors.list`

Also, if you use this solution, you should be aware to add the category query parameter to the pagination links too.

Comment: I'm trying your solution right now, but I'm getting this error:

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'category_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `doctors` where `category_id` = 1)

Still trying to figure it.

If I just check with this code in my view it displays the category_id fine:
{{ $doctor->category_id }}

Comment: it is pretty clear.. how do you named the category column on the doctors table?

Comment: it's category_id

Comment: Then something's strange there.. it shouldn't throw any error if the `category_id` column is there..

Comment: Yes, it doesn't make any sense. I'm researching now.

Comment: By the way, this is my route: Route::get('/doctors', 'DoctorsController@doctorsList')->name('doctorsList');

I've already changed it in the code, but I'm still getting that unknown column error.

Comment: What db do you use? mysql?

Comment: Yes, I use MySQL and every column has utf8mb4_unicode_ci, so the error lies somewhere.

Comment: you have to change category_id for 'id'

Comment: please put more info in your post, like your table structure  in sql

Comment: Matei, I've tried the updated controller method and I'm getting this error: Non-static method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::newQuery() should not be called statically

Comment: I've just tried now again. Unfortunately I'm still getting the Column not found error.
You can check my updated thread.

Comment: I've solved the problem! :)
The column not found error was because in the controller code part "where" should be "whereTranslation", because Laravel translatable plugin uses this function for filtering the content.

Now everything works great!

Comment: Matei, please change that part in your code and I'll accept your answer and +1 from me, of course. Thank you very much!

Comment: @user2519032 glad to hear that! updated the answer.. good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution in this solution you will not require any server call

just give id to the `<div class="article">`

give id as `docs-categoryid-doctorid`

now on your `<select name="category_id" onchange="showhidedocs();">`

```
function showhidedocs(){
      var cat=$('#category_id').val();
            if(cat!="all"){
             $('[id^=docs-]').hide();
             var temp="[id^=docs-"+cat+']';
             $(temp).show();
                          }else{
                              $('[id^=docs-]').show();
                              }
                       }
```

Comment: wow no! If you have 10k doctors what do you do? This is for sure a bad idea!

Comment: @MateiMihai number of doctors to be displayed has been filtered in controller before only, now filter is just among the present docs on screen

Comment: @MateiMihai my solution is purely based on question not your assumptions.

Comment: Hello, phpdroid. I've chosen the other answer because I need a server side for filtering, but your answer is good too. Thank you very much for your answer too, I'll test it later. +1 from me! :)

Comment: Glad i hope this can help someone in future.